# In Snowflake Kafka connector can we define file type

Tags: arrays, json, apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake kafka connector can I use predefined data type since internally it uses snowpipe to data loading.

What i am trying to achieve over here is to remove outer array from my json msg while loading data to stage table.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an option for this today.  You could create a stream on the destination Kafka table and a task based on the stream.  Then transform to a new table without the outer array of the json.

I would recommend filing a new idea as this would be a good feature request:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to create a view on the table that Kafka connector loads data.

I have several similar cases, created views to manipulate data for consumption and masking PII information without the need of a secondary table or process.

If data volume gets big and/or your view performance does not meet your needs, you can always create a materialized view.